# Shortcut to switch between normal view & reading view in Outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook, keyboard-shortcuts

We have two buttons to switch between normal view & reading view in Outlook but <kbd>F1</kbd> doesn't have any entry about what key we could use to switch between these buttons.

Anyone know about it?

[image]

Comment: There does not seem to be a keyboard shortcut and since Outlook doesn't have the same macro capabilities as Word/Excel, this will be challenging. Nevertheless, some clever AutoHotkey could get the job done. I'll give this a shot later. :)

Comment: @iglvzx Have you attempted this yet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd> to cycle between normal/reading views.

Comment: No, Alt-F1 does not cycle between Normal/Reading views. It cycles the Navigation Pane (the far-left column in the screenshot) between Normal/Minimized/Off. Similarly, Alt-F2 cycles the To-Do Bar (far right pane), and Ctrl-F1 cycles the Ribbon Bar. While useful, it takes all three shortcuts combined to mimic the Reading view.

Answer (score -1):

By accident I found out that ALT+FN+2 works as an On/Off toggle for this for me.

Comment: `Fn` key is not standardized. It exists only on laptops and does different things on different models. In this case `Fn`+`2` is producing some mystery key press and `Alt`+`MysteryKey` does what you want - but we don't know what the `MysteryKey` is so this is only useful for users with laptops similar to yours. Are there any extra symbols on the `2` key?

Comment: @gronstaj Fn keys also are on many Desktop computers. They often are used to bypass custom keyboard settings from the manufacturer. -- Eric this is likely specific to your computer. You should specify which computer and OS you are using.